# Android problems when creating new activity: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I'm trying to create a popupmenu when I click a button through a new activity but I have always the same problem and I searched for a solution but I cant see it by myself. Maybe it's something stupid that I'm doing but I started a few days with Android.

The logcat is this:

```
03-14 11:46:37.581 9653-9653/info.androidhive.navigationdrawer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: info.androidhive.navigationdrawer, PID: 9653
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.navigationdrawer/info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
 at info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
 at info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69) 
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
 at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:36)
 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:185)
 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:179)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
 at info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69) 
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

My MainActivity:

```
package info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.R;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.GenerarFragment;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.PasswordsFragment;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.SettingsFragment;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.other.CircleTransform;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private View navHeader;
    private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
    private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;

    // urls to load navigation header background image
    // and profile image
    private static final String urlNavHeaderBg = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/nav-menu-header-bg.jpg";
    private static final String urlProfileImg = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/eCtE_G34M9ygdkmOpYvCag1vBARCmZwnVS6rS5t4JLzJ6QgQSBquM0nuTsCpLhYbKljoyS-txg";

    // index to identify current nav menu item
    public static int navItemIndex = 0;

    // tags used to attach the fragments
    private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHOTOS = "photos";
    private static final String TAG_SETTINGS = "settings";
    public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

    // toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
    private String[] activityTitles;

    // flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
    private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private static Button button_sbm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        // Navigation view header
        navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.website);
        imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
        imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

        // load toolbar titles from string resources
        activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        // load nav menu header data
        loadNavHeader();

        // initializing navigation menu
        setUpNavigationView();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
        }
        OnClickButtonListener();
    }

    public void OnClickButtonListener(){
        button_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        Intent intent = new Intent("info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.RegisterForContextMenuActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    /***
     * Load navigation menu header information
     * like background image, profile image
     * name, website, notifications action view (dot)
     */
    private void loadNavHeader() {
        // name, website
        txtName.setText("Ravi Tamada");
        txtWebsite.setText("www.androidhive.info");

        // loading header background image
        Glide.with(this).load(urlNavHeaderBg)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgNavHeaderBg);

        // Loading profile image
        Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
                .crossFade()
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgProfile);
    }

    /***
     * Returns respected fragment that user
     * selected from navigation menu
     */
    private void loadHomeFragment() {
        // selecting appropriate nav menu item
        selectNavMenu();

        // set toolbar title
        setToolbarTitle();

        // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
        // just close the navigation drawer
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();

            // show or hide the fab button
            toggleFab();
            return;
        }

        // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
        // when switching between navigation menus
        // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect
        // This effect can be seen in GMail app
        Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // update the main content by replacing fragments
                Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        };

        // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
        if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
            mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
        }

        // show or hide the fab button
        toggleFab();

        //Closing drawer on item click
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        // refresh toolbar menu
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
        switch (navItemIndex) {
            case 0:
                // home
                PasswordsFragment passwordsFragment = new PasswordsFragment();
                return passwordsFragment;
            case 1:
                // photos
                GenerarFragment generarFragment = new GenerarFragment();
                return generarFragment;
            case 2:
                // settings fragment
                SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
                return settingsFragment;
            default:
                return new PasswordsFragment();
        }
    }

    private void setToolbarTitle() {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
    }

    private void selectNavMenu() {
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
    }

    private void setUpNavigationView() {
        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.home:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_photos:
                        navItemIndex = 1;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PHOTOS;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_settings:
                        navItemIndex = 2;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_about_us:
                        // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_privacy_policy:
                        // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrivacyPolicyActivity.class));
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                }

                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                }
                menuItem.setChecked(true);

                loadHomeFragment();

                return true;
            }
        });


        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();
            return;
        }

        // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
        // when user is in other fragment than home
        if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
            // checking if user is on other navigation menu
            // rather than home
            if (navItemIndex != 0) {
                navItemIndex = 0;
                CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                loadHomeFragment();
                return;
            }
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        // show menu only when home fragment is selected
        if (navItemIndex == 0) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // show or hide the fab
    private void toggleFab() {
        if (navItemIndex == 0)
            fab.show();
        else
            fab.hide();
    }
}
```

This is the layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is AndroidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.navigationdrawer">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.RegisterForContextMenuActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.AboutUsActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_title_about_us" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PrivacyPolicyActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_title_privacy_policy" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.RegisterForContextMenuActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Style.xml:

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Comment: can you please share layout xml and AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.`

Comment: @MukeshJha I just added them :D

Answer (score 0):

As the stack trace mention : Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
your problem is in your Activity theme. 
What can I see in your AndroidManifest file that the MainActivity have a custom theme "**@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar**", so please make sure that **your custom AppTheme has a parent Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).**

Comment: I added style.xml to first post, Theme.AppCompat is in partent. I don't know why It shows then the exception

Comment: This is very strange, normally this exception is thrown when the theme doesn't have the attribute 'colorPrimary' wich is by default in AppCompat theme. I made a sample app with your code and it works fine for me.